# PHP, curl, Unable to set custom header

Tags: php, curl

Somehow I cannot set custom headers for the PHP curl call. The following code is working on my server (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu, curl version 7.40.0) but it does not work on the server of our customer (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, curl version 7.43.0).

```
    $bodyString = json_encode($body);
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => 0,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH => CURLAUTH_BASIC,
        CURLOPT_USERPWD => "$customerId:$licenceKey",
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE,
        CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT  => TRUE,

        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
            'Content-Type: application/json',
            'Content-Length: ' . strlen($bodyString),
        ),
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $bodyString
    );

    log("Requesting [".$url."]...");

    $cURL = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($cURL, $options);
    $response = curl_exec($cURL);

    log("Header dump:\n ".curl_getinfo($cURL, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT));
```

On our server it works as expected and CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT returns:

```
POST /api/rest_call?p1=true&p2=true HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic *****
Host: admin.myserver.net
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 119
```

On the customers server the CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT returns an empty string. The requested server returns "415 Unsupported media type" because no "Content-Type" was transferred.

**UPDATE**: Followed the hint from [Php - Debugging Curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl/14436877#14436877) I created the verbose log file. Here is a part of it:

```
POST /api/rest_call?p1=true&p2=true HTTP/1.1
Host: admin.yoochoose.net
Accept: */*
```

All the custom headers and(!) the authentication information seems to be ignored by cURL. Any ideas?

Comment: Check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl/14436877#14436877 how to debug your curl problem (verbos may be helpful..)

Comment: Just remove   'Content-Length: ' . strlen($bodyString) and retry.. I am not sure but normally, Content-Length is a response header not request header.

Comment: Check MIME-type configuration on the client server for "application/javascript"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` must be removed. For POST requests it is useless anyway.

I cannot investigate it deeply. It is not my server. As far I as know it is linked to the PHP safe mode or similar restriction. It blocks local file system requests outside the `www` folder and symlink usage. It affects the `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` options.

[PHP safe_mode problem using curl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147170/php-safe-mode-problem-using-curl)

It is an old problem. But I did not know, it removes all the headers from the request as well.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use name containing '_' in your header, try using '-' instead.

If you want you need to set underscores_in_headers on in your nginx config.

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856136/why-do-http-servers-forbid-underscores-in-http-header-names)

Comment: Thanks for this. Used underscores on another project where these were allowed, didn't think twice. So yes, using dashes, the server rewrites it to HTTP_ converting the hyphens to underscores.